# Force Page initialization

Tags: asp.net

The following code is not causing `Page_Load` of `PhotoList` to be called.  I want the control to be initialized as if it is in normal Page live cycle, what I should do.

```
Page pageHolder = new Page();
UserControl viewControl = (UserControl)pageHolder.LoadControl("Common/PhotoList.ascx");
pageHolder.Controls.Add(viewControl);
```

Comment: Where is the code being called from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the pageHolder and why are you creating a new instance of it? The normal pattern is like so where you load the control into a place holder control.

UserControl viewControl = (UserControl)**Page**.LoadControl("Common/PhotoList.ascx"); 
**placeHolder**.Controls.Add(viewControl);

Calling Page.Load will cause the Page_Load event to fire.

Comment: I need to create an AJAX response, which require to render the control as a string and send it back to the client, it will not render correctly till it is in a dummy page and also the page should have a normal life cycle which I cannot force.

Comment: What code do you have in the Page_Load event of PhotoList.ascx?

Comment: Not the Page_Load I need to make the page live cycle work because an ObjectDataSource is not behaving correctly.

Comment: In your original question you said "The following code is not causing Page_Load".. Please give more details as to what is "not behaving correctly"

Comment: I suspect that ObjectDataSource cannot see total rows although SelectCountMethod is returning the correct total rows, and ObjectDatatSource is keep sending pageSize =-1, and other things,  something unknown is not working, and it will probably work if I made it just build like any normal page life cycle.  So I want to try it.

Comment: Create an empty aspx page foo.aspx, and the PhotoList.ascx page. Go to foo.aspx from your browser. Does everything execute correctly?